# Header background is not expanding until the end of screen

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is a screenshot from the website. Computer browsers shows very well but mobile opera and other browsers shows like that.

What am I missing?

```
#header{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg,#307FB7, #084F81);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg,#307FB7, #084F81);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(180deg,#307FB7, #084F81);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(180deg,#307FB7, #084F81);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#307FB7, #084F81);


    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
}

#header-wrapper{
    height: 80px;
    margin: auto; /* Centralize blue bar */
    width: 996px; /* Fix the size of blue bar */
}
```

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1. The space is > 996px width. 2. The website is holding some space for possible scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Set width in `#header-wrapper` from `"width: 996px;"` to `"width: 100%;"`

So your header wrapper will extend full width of the page

Comment: If there was some html here I could explain what is going on in this situation. Its hard with just css.

Comment: Your last line is good enough for what you are given to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but why do you have `width:996px;`?

If you need it that width on browsers, use `max-width: 996px;` and `width:100%;`

That way in mobile the bar will be 100% of your screen, but in browser it will be 100% until it hits the max of 996px.

Comment: Could you link me to the site and I'll check it there?